# set font size only for the gnome terminal tab

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

When i try to set font size for the terminal, it changes across all open tabs. Thing is I just need it to be reduced on one tab and continue with the default on others. is that possible? E.g one tab I keep it at 9 and other at default -12. Reason is on a couple of tabs i am observing some running processes which i have to fit into the screen but at the same time, don't want to squint while doing other dev work. Thanks

Comment: Create a terminal profile with font size what ever you want and load a new terminal tab and choose that profile.https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-profiles.html.en

Comment: does it put extra load on graphics? When i am switching tabs, i can see unity struggle it seems :)

Comment: Depends upon your hardware spec's and Graphic drivers etc. but loading profile has nothing to do with graphic card /display

Comment: @Ten-Coin Either that, or just use "Ctrl +" or "Ctrl -" to zoom in/out.